# Mongodb with pymongo and $push performing cleaning the list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to Add one `dict` within a list in MongoDB, order by date and cut the old ones.

The following code do the job perfectly, when running directly in MongoDB  (using robomongo client):

```
db.products.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("549598b641ba00e6b7aacd45") },
    {
        $push: {
            prices: {
                $each: [{'d': ISODate("2015-01-13T01:13:00.201Z"), 'v': 105.3}],
                $sort: {'d': -1},
                $slice: -30
            }
        }
    }
)
```

but when I rewrite the operation in PyMongo and execute, it firstly clear the old array and add just the new one, leaving with one record.

PyMongo Code:

```
self.db['products'].update(
    {'source_url': item['source_url']},
    {
        '$push': {
            'prices': {
                '$each': [{'d': datetime.utcnow(), 'v': 107.8}],
                # '$sort': {'d': -1},
                # '$slice': -30
            }
        }
    },
)
```

Even commented the `sort` and `slice` the `push` operation aren't maintained the old ones.

The process are running inside scrapy 0.24.4 pipeline, PyMongo Version 2.7.1, Mongo Version 2.6.4

---

**Problem Solved**: I was using `find_and_modify` in other function before those code losting all data

Comment: The `upsert = True` means that a document will be create if your selection does not find a match. So it is irrelevant for your case.

Comment: Are you using ordered dictionary to construct the update object?   Python doesn't guarantee order in regular dictionaries.

Comment: what do you mean by "find_and_modify" doesn't preserve data? it works exactly the same as "update" - if you $set new fields (or $push, etc) then it adds them, if you provide a full new document, it replaces existing document.

Comment: Thank you @AsyaKamsky, It would be very useful. I saw in the docs early and it isn't clear about the other use of find_and_modify with $set/$push, thank you really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me with PyMongo:

```
>>> db = MongoClient().test
>>> db.products.insert({'source_url': 'x'})
ObjectId('54ba45a6ca1ce9489f5778b2')
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> db.products.update({'source_url': 'x'}, {'$push': {
            'prices': {
                '$each': [{'d': datetime.utcnow(), 'v': 107.8}]}}})
>>> len(db.products.find_one()['prices'])
1
>>> db.products.update({'source_url': 'x'}, {'$push': {
            'prices': {
                '$each': [{'d': datetime.utcnow(), 'v': 107.8}]}}})
>>> len(db.products.find_one()['prices'])
2
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried with _id to see, the result is the same, I lost all prices date before inserting.

Comment: Executing your code in my collection (using ipython) it work correctly, then I copied the same update instruction (with direct ObjectId) and execute inside scrapy and it performs and before.

Comment: I've edited my answer, perhaps it's an order-of-operators issue with MongoDB 2.4?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate that. But the solution dont worked for me, even because the error appears with just $each then order-of-operators doesn't matter. I've edited my question with the versions i'm using. I've Schedule to watch your PyCon 2014 Async presentation, cya.

Comment: Right, understood. Your code works for me, sorry I don't know what the problem is. Hope you figure it out!

Comment: Jesse, I solved the problem, it was my fault, I've edited my question with the solution, thank you again.